# HTML5 tag to wrap interactive content?

Tags: html, seo, standards

I have an interactive content piece on a page within a great deal of content, which is well sectioned into hierarchies. This piece takes input from a couple of form elements and outputs responses via javascript. Is there a specific type of HTML5 tag that is appropriate to wrap this content?

Comment: Can you give an actual example?

Comment: @unor I have a calculator for automobile equity as one example. I cannot show it yet as the site is not yet public. There are several similar "calculators" around the site. I was wondering if there's a specific tag or method for letting google/etc know that this wasn't normal content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly, the [`output` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/forms.html#the-output-element) might be appropriate:

> […] represents the result of a calculation or user action.

You can use its `for` attribute to denote which form elements take part in the calculation of the result.